# How to print text without initial line number in R?

Tags: r, indexing, character

I want to print a character in r, whiteout line number ! How do I do that :

```
print("character ",quote = FALSE , row.names = F)
[1] character
```

The `row.names = F` does not do anything !
I would like to have :

```
print("character ",quote = FALSE, something to remove the line index)
     character
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options:

1) Create a data.frame then unname it, clunky but gets the job done and may not generalize well.

```
print(unname(as.data.frame("character")),quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

2) use the `messages`. If you are in RStudio the text will be a different color but will not print the indexes.

```
`message("character")`
```

Comment: This answer is on the edge of a downvote in my opinion (I won't downvote it btw). Such a messy trick to just write a string on stdout. R has function for this purpose and it's `cat`. The 1) approach has to be strongly discouraged. The second approach just makes use of a function that has other purposes.

Comment: @user9112767 this is not the right answer. Saurabh Chauhan is the correct answer, please unaccept this one and accept the correct answer

Comment: `message` is a legit answer as `cat` might be annoying regarding new lines. with package crayon the issue of colors could be  solved : `message(black("character"))` (if black is your default color)

Answer (score 14):

Simply use `cat`:

```
 cat("character")
```

Output:

```
 character
```